# Automatically Decrease Cell A by value of cell B and keep current Cell B value saved even when Cell A is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have successfully made Cell B value decrease by value of Cell A. But is it possible to keep Cell B's decreased value even when Cell A is left blank after.

Cell B is the database
Cell A is a field to enter how much to decrease from current value. However it is pointless if the database doesn't save after value is decreased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a stored value and a calculation value, but it will require a manual action every time.

In column A, you place the values that modify the value. In column B you place the current database value. In Column C you put your formula with the outcome: example `=B1-A1`.

When all cells in Column A have been entered and column C contains all new values, Select entire Column C and press `Copy`. Then select entire Column B, and rightclick and select `paste special`. Then in the next dialog, select Paste values. Then clear the values in Column A.

Now, the problem you'll get that if Column A does contain anything other than a value, Column C will display an error there (`#VALUE!`). If you copy that to column B, it will lose the value it had stored. You can place an IF function in Column C to prevent this from becoming a problem, using the `=ISNUMBER` function. Your new formula in Column C becomes `=IF(ISNUMBER(A1);B1-A1;B1)`
This basically will execute the calculation if Column A has a number, and if not, only give whatever is in Column B.

If you want to automate this process, you'll have to use macro's.